# Updating row in JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, derby

I am currently trying to create a java file to allow for a basic user interface to connect to a derby client server. I need to update a row in a student courses table where the user will know the StudentID (SID) and may will need to enter the students courses 1, 2, and 3 and the Course cost 1, 2, 3 and change them to the new data entered. and the Student Course ID SCID and SID should remain unchanged currently I am using methods to obtain the data from the user and store this data in variables in the Java and then I need to be able to search by the SID but not change it and then enter the remaining data.
I have been trying to use prepared statements to achieve this but I am having issues.

```
---SQLException Caught---

  SQLState:   XCL14
  Severity: 20000
  Message:  The column position '10' is out of range.  The number of columns for t
        his ResultSet is '9'.
  java.sql.SQLException: The column position '10' is out of range.  The number of
  columns for this ResultSet is '9'.
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unkn
  own Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Sourc
  e)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.ColumnMetaData.getColumnType(Unknown Sourc
  e)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.setString(Unknown Source
  )
          at StudentPayments.main(StudentPayments.java:186)
  Caused by: org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException: The column position '10' is
  out of range.  The number of columns for this ResultSet is '9'.
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.ColumnMetaData.checkForValidColumnIndex(Un
  known Source)
    ... 3 more
  Students database finishing. . . .
```

Here is the schema of the table

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT_COURSES
(SCID INT NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    SID INT ,
    CID1 INT ,
    CID2 INT ,
    CID3 INT ,
    CC1 INT ,
    CC2 INT ,
    CC3 INT ,
    TOTAL INT ,
    foreign key (SID) references STUDENT(SID),
    foreign key (CID1) references COURSES(CID),
    foreign key (CID2) references COURSES(CID),
    foreign key (CID3) references COURSES(CID),
    UNIQUE (TOTAL)
    );
```

This is what I have in the Java but it isn't working

```
PreparedStatement scUpdate;
ResultSet StudentCourse;
String SCID, CID1, CID2, CID3, CC1, CC2, CC3;
String studentTotalCost;
String responseSC;

stuUpdate = connect.prepareStatement("UPDATE STUDENT SET FIRSTNAME = ?, LASTNAME = ?, DOB = ?, ADDRESS = ?, SUBURB = ?, PROVINCE = ?, POSTCODE = ?, PHONE = ?, EMAIL = ? WHERE SID = ?");

responseSC=getTableChoiceFromUser();
if( ( responseSC.substring(0,1).equals("3") || responseSC.substring(0,Math.min(responseSC.length(),mUpdate.length())).toUpperCase().equals(mUpdate) ))
//checks the Users selection                        
{
    SID = getStudentSIDFromUser();
    if(! SID.substring(0,Math.min(SID.length(),mEXIT.length())).toUpperCase().equals(mEXIT) )
    //checks to make sure User does not want to exit this step and return to start.
    {
        CID1 = getCIDFromUser();
        CID2 = getCIDFromUser();
        CID3 = getCIDFromUser();
        CC1 = getCCFromUser();
        CC2 = getCCFromUser();
        CC3 = getCCFromUser();
        SCID = getCIDFromUser();
        studentTotalCost = CC1 + CC2 + CC3;
        scUpdate.setString(1, SID);
        scUpdate.setString(2, CID1);
        scUpdate.setString(3, CID2);
        scUpdate.setString(4, CID3);
        scUpdate.setString(5, CC1);
        scUpdate.setString(6, CC2);
        scUpdate.setString(7, CC3);
        scUpdate.setString(8, studentTotalCost);
        scUpdate.setString(9, SCID);
        scUpdate.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println(Bar);
        System.out.println("Students Courses Successfully Updated.");
        System.out.println(Bar);
    }
```

Comment: Have you forget to `commit` the updates?

Comment: Auto Commit hasn't been turned off so should automatically commit.

Comment: Is there an error or exception? What, precisely, is your question?

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention the exception I've been getting.

I have updated the question.

Comment: As is, your code prepares statement `stuUpdate` for table `STUDENT`, and uses `scUpdate` for table `STUDENT_COURSES` for which you do not show how it is prepared. Cannot help more without it.

Comment: Where do you initialize the `scUpdate` variable?

Answer (score 0):

The exception code looks strange, because you are not referring any "?" that is not present in the statement. HOWEVER note that you supplied only 9 arguments to the statement not 10 - this could cause the problem.

Comment: I thought by supplying the 10th argument it would allow me to use that 10th argument as the value for "where SID = ?" is this not the way to do this? if not how do I change this to allow it to search by the SID that the user enters? thank you

Comment: Your last argument should correspond to the last in the statement that is exactly "where SID = ?". Look at the example here: http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-update-a-record/ . If your SID column is INT you should add setInt() call on PreparedStatement before calling executeUpdate().